# post Notification Delayed

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm trying to post Notifications via AlarmManager delayed. For this purpose I created an AlarmReciever which currently looks like this:

```
public class NotificationAlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

public static final String TAG = "NotificationAlarmReciever";

public static final String KEY_NOTIFICATION_EXTRA = "NotificationExtra";
public static final String KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID = "NotificationId";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    LogCat.d(TAG, "AlarmReciever Triggered");
    LogIntent(intent);
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    if (b != null){
        if (b.containsKey(KEY_NOTIFICATION_EXTRA)){
            Notification n = b.<Notification>getParcelable(KEY_NOTIFICATION_EXTRA);
                    int request = 100
                    if(b.containsKey(KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID)){
                        request = b.getInt(KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID)
                    }
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(request, n);
        }
    }
}

private void LogIntent(Intent intent) {
    //logs Intent....

}
}
```

I created a TestActivty where I try to start an Alarm like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Context c = getApplicationContext();
            int requestCode = 333;

            Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.balloon_overlay_close,"ticker", System.currentTimeMillis() + Integer.parseInt(mWhen.getText().toString()));
            Intent notificationAction = new Intent(c, TestActivity.class);
            PendingIntent notificationPendingOperation = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, requestCode, notificationAction, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(c, "HEADER", "MESSAGE", notificationPendingOperation);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(c, NotificationAlarmReciever.class);
            alarmIntent.putExtra(NotificationAlarmReciever.KEY_NOTIFICATION_EXTRA, notification);
            PendingIntent alarmOperation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, requestCode, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//Line 127
            alarmManager.set(requestCode, notification.when, alarmOperation);
}
```

as soon as alarmManager.set is called I get a NullPointerException saying:

```
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set(IAlarmManager.java:174)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at android.app.AlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.java:139)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at de.eos.uptrade.android.core.TestActivity$1.onClick(TestActivity.java:127)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-01 16:37:15.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4422):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I dont know, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you get a nullpointerexception in your onclick method. please identify the exact line that the exception occurs in. Then try to deduce which object accessed in that line is null. Then update your question.

Comment: @videre my OnClick Method is what you see second - where I create the Alarm -  
Line 127 is alarmManager.set

Comment: alright, do you know how to debug? put a breakpoint at line 127, run the app, and when the program reaches the breakpoint, hover your cursor over each object in line 127 until you identify the one that is null. Then update here

Comment: @videre sorry. I know how to debug. My Problem is that I couln't find an Object, which is null. Everything seems to be setted correctly

Comment: alright, i think i found the problem, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [AlarmManager.set(...) documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#pubmethods).

There you can see that the first parameter 'type' cannot be 333. It can be set to either ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC or RTC_WAKEUP, which correspond to the integer values 3, 2, 1 and 0. Those are your choices.

Comment: thx, that worked... I think the expression "NullPointerException" is misleading. "IllegalArgumentException" would be better